# How do I debug what seems like timing related rspec test fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am going through the rails tutorial and I am up to a point where I have quite a few tests (124).

I am starting to run into an issue in which sometimes a set of tests will randomly fail, but when I try to reproduce them using the same seed, they pass.  The fails seem to be mainly related to a FactoryGirl sequence used to generate unique user emails.  Most of the time the tests all pass,  and if I run with out providing a seed these fails popup maybe 10% of the time.

Here is an example of what I am seeing:

[image]

Here is the rspec test code that seems to **sometimes** fail

```
describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
      after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each user" do
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
          page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
        end
      end
    end
```

---

Here is the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end
  factory :micropost do
    content "Lorem ipsum"
    user
  end
end
```

**Update:**
The issue is related to the test database not being cleaned up after some tests.  I could (and did) find the tests that were creating the user. 
I decided to use the database_cleaner gem and configure it as recommended here:
[configuring database_cleaner](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/)

Comment: This might be related to your question: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories

Comment: Is it possible your test database isn't empty when your tests start? Are you running with transactions on?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I am not sure, how would I check that?

Comment: I just found that i can reproduce this if I rerun rspec twice.  the first time I run it with the seed that passed just before the run with the seed that failed.  So it is something to do with the "state" of the application (or database) prior to running the tests

Comment: Execute `rails dbconsole test` from the command line and then do a `select * from users;`.

Comment: If you haven't done a `rails generate rspec:install`, you might not be running with transactions. See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions

Comment: @PeterAlfvin select * from user;  does return some users

Comment: Assuming those users pre-existing in your test database have the same format names and emails as those generated by your factory and assuming you don't clear them out at the beginning of your test, then you'll get an error whenever get "up to" that sequence value in your factory.

Comment: yes, this is the issue. As you can see the pagination test above does clean up after itself.  I am sure I have another test that creates a user for some other purpose and that does not clean up after it self.  Maybe I should ask this in another question, but what is a good strategy for cleaning up the test database?  a before  :all to delete all the users, after :all, or both?

Comment: See my earlier comment about transactions. Have done the `rails generate rspec:install` step?  Are you requiring `rspec_helper` in your specs?  That should take care of it.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Using DatabaseCleaner did seem to fix the problem, but I see your point.  I must have done the rails generate rspec:install step because I did have config.use_transactional_fixtures = true in spec_helper and was requiring it. So according to the doc, that should have taken care of it (as you say).

Comment: Perhaps you are creating some test data outside of your RSpec `it` blocks. RSpec creates a transaction for each example and rolls back after it completes (or aborts), but that won't address any database writes occurring outside of an example.

Comment: I think I see test data being created outside "it" blocks... http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up?version=3.2#code-user_show_page_test  ... I am following the rails tutorial.  I was not having any issues __before__ I added some new tests (as part of exercises).  I will have to go back and study this more closely

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps previous tests are setting these users. Try putting the User.delete_all in the before filter before creating them.